# const reference syntax difference between visual studio and gcc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(float& const a, float& const b)
{}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

This simple code compiles in Visual studio (vs2013) but not in gcc. I have tried c++ 10 and also c++11. gcc gives an error saying

> error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'float&'

But if I change the function definition to

```
void swap(float const &a, float const &b)
```

it compiles in gcc and also visual studio.

My question is, does both these syntaxes mean the same thing? Also, why it compiles with visual studio and not with gcc

Comment: Intuitively the signature should be `void swap(const float& a, const float& b)`.

Comment: There's no C++10. You probably mean 98 or 03.

Comment: Visual Studio is wrong (yet again).

Comment: Don't know if the first syntax is legal, but it shouldn't have any effect, because you cant change the target of a reference anyway. The second syntax and the one proposed by @πάνταῥεῖ have a different meaning.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Intuitively it should be `void swap( ref<const float> a, ref<const float> b )`, and one can define a template `ref` for this use. This works with simple type deduction for template overload resolution. But `auto` type deduction is somewhat problematic, not the same rules.

Comment: I wouldn't call Visual Studio "wrong" even if I don't like it that much either. It's just handling the error in another way: `warning C4227: anachronism used : qualifiers on reference are ignored`.

Comment: @Cheers Agreed Chuck! Let's have a cigar ;-) ...

Answer (score 4):

`float& const a` is invalid. A reference cannot be `const`. It can refer to a `const` object but it cannot itself be `const` (it would be meaningless since it's not reseatable).

**C++14 §8.3.2/1:**

> **”**  Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
>   through the use of a *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1) or *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

A *decltype-specifier* is a use of the `decltype` keyword.

---

Visual C++ 2015 does warn about it (at warning level 4):

```
C:\my\forums\so\141> cl foo.cpp /Feb
foo.cpp
foo.cpp(3): warning C4227: anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored
foo.cpp(3): warning C4100: 'b': unreferenced formal parameter
foo.cpp(3): warning C4100: 'a': unreferenced formal parameter

C:\my\forums\so\141> g++ foo.cpp -Wno-unused-parameter
foo.cpp:3:24: error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'float&'
 void swap(float& const a, float& const b)
                        ^
foo.cpp:3:40: error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'float&'
 void swap(float& const a, float& const b)
                                        ^

C:\my\forums\so\141> _
```